# NHibernate ManyToMany and eager loading: strange resultset for SetFetchmode combined with SetResultTransformer and SetMaxResult

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many

I've got a many-to-many relationship which I try to fetch eager:

```
*.CreateCriteria(typeof(Class1))
.SetFetchMode("Class2", FetchMode.Eager)
.SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
.SetFirstResult(20)
.SetMaxResult(10)
.List<Class1>();
```

I'd like to have rows 20-30 returned, but instead I've got 12-18. Why? Because the SetResultTransformer is executed AFTER the SetMaxResult. It returns 10 rows starting from row 20, but then it is distincted (is that a word?) resulting in rows 12-18.
I totally understand what's happening, but can't think of a solution using criteria...

Does anyone have a solution to that?

Comment: don't have a solution but do know the cause... that is more than half the battle.  see answer.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221482/nhibernate-eager-loading-collections-paging?

Answer (score 1):

It is because the SetMaxResults method works at a 'low level'. 
I mean, SetMaxResults causes the SQL statement that is generated by NHibernate to contain a `TOP` or `LIMIT` clause.

Ofcourse, this leads to those strange results when you're using an eager fetching-mode, since the eager fetchmode results in a JOIN.

So, if you have 2 tables that are joined together in a one-to-many relationship, the recordset that is returned by NHibernate looks like this for instance

```
1 recordA-fromTable1  1 recordX-fromTable2
2 recordA-fromTable1  2 recordY-fromTable2
3 recordB-fromTable1  3 record2-fromTable2
```

If a 'TOP 2' is performed on the above recordset, NHibernate will only be able to extract one entity from it, since the first 2 records in the resultset, are actually for the same entity.

I've resolved this by using a detached subquery, that contains the TOP clause, and retrieves the ID's of the entities that have to be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

I did not actually try this, but it might work.

```
  *.CreateCriteria(typeof(Class1))
    .SetFirstResult(20)
    .SetMaxResult(10)
    .CreateCriteria("Class2", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    .SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
    .List<Class1>();
```

EDIT: This does not work.
Use multiquery, multicriteria (or Future when using a new build of NH)

Comment: I tried it.  It doesn't work.  It has the exact same problem as the original post.

Comment: I know now, it's not possible because it's a very inefficient query. You should use multiquery

Comment: Could you provide a few more details (preferably examples specific to this question) on how to use the multicriteria, multiquery, and Future features?  I'm also having the same problem, and I'm not quite sure how to go about using the features mentioned to accomplish the goal of this question.

Comment: Nathan, you might like to read this:

http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/09/06/eager-loading-aggregate-with-many-child-collections.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  An adaptation of the following using detached criteria and subqueries looks like it might be promising.  I'm going to do a more thorough trial of it when I get some time.

http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2008/11/20/nhibernate-criteria-queries-across-multiple-many-many-associations/

Answer (score 0):

```
 public List<Employee> getData(int to, int from,
        String searchField, String searchString, String searchOper,
        String sord, String sidx) {

            Criteria hCriteria = null;
    List<Employee> viewDataList = null;
            List<Employee> exactDataList = null;
    try {

        hSession = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
        hTransaction = hSession.beginTransaction();
        hCriteria = hSession.createCriteria(Employee.class);

        if (searchString != null && searchField != null
                && searchOper != null) {
            if (searchOper.equalsIgnoreCase("eq"))


                    hCriteria.add(Restrictions
                            .eq(searchField, searchString));


            if (searchOper.equalsIgnoreCase("ne"))
                hCriteria.add(Restrictions.ne(searchField, searchString));
            if (searchOper.equalsIgnoreCase("lt"))
                hCriteria.add(Restrictions.lt(searchField, searchString));
            if (searchOper.equalsIgnoreCase("le"))
                hCriteria.add(Restrictions.le(searchField, searchString));
            if (searchOper.equalsIgnoreCase("gt"))
                hCriteria.add(Restrictions.gt(searchField, searchString));
            if (searchOper.equalsIgnoreCase("ge"))
                hCriteria.add(Restrictions.ge(searchField, searchString));
            if (searchOper.equalsIgnoreCase("cn"))
                hCriteria.add(Restrictions.ilike(searchField, searchString,
                        MatchMode.ANYWHERE));

        }


        if (sord != null && sidx != null && !sidx.equals("")) {
            if (sord.equals("asc"))
                hCriteria.addOrder(Order.asc(sidx));
            else
                hCriteria.addOrder(Order.desc(sidx));

        }

        /*
                    hCriteria.setFirstResult(to);
        hCriteria.setFirstResult(from);
                    */
        hCriteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
        viewDataList = hCriteria.list();

                  // for limit
                 exactDataList=viewDataList.subList(from,to);

                hTransaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        hTransaction.rollback();

    } finally {
        try {
            hSession.flush();
            HibernateSessionFactory.closeSession();
        } catch (Exception hExp) {
        }

    }

    return exactDataList;

}
```