# NHibernate Eager Loading Collections + Paging

Tags: nhibernate, pagination, eager-loading

Here is an example of my entities that I am trying to return with eager loaded collections.

Mixes
 -> Tracks (collection)
 -> Tags (collection)

I need to return a paged list of Mixes with eager loaded tracks & tags, without paging it is relativly simple by using the Future<>() function to run multiple queries for the tracks + tags.

Because this data needs to be paged...how can I get all my data back so that NHibernate won't get the N+1 issue when displaying my data.

Paul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Fetch the Mixes page you want, **without** any Tracks or Tags.
2. Fetch all the Tracks (left join Tags) that correspond to the all the Mixes you fetched in the step above (i.e. if you're using HQL, use [SetParameterList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401950/nhibernate-hql-where-in-query) to pass all the Mixes IDs)

Total: 2 queries.

Comment: when you say corresponding to the mixes, do you mean by doing a IN() clause from the ID's of my mixes?